# Javascript slow on IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance, internet-explorer

We're using jQueryUI dialog in our MVC applications in many places. This one dialog has around 10,000 html elements within it (rows of span, inputs, `<br/>`, etc.)

Only in IE9, when trying to use the `dialog('destroy')` method, the browser becomes unresponsive and takes about a minute or two to actually "close" the dialog. We have tried different approaches to speed up the "closing" the dialog, including a custom dialog with plain javascript with

- `outerHtml = "";`
- `element.parentNode.removeChild(element);`

We know that the problem lies with the quantity of content in the dialog because the time it takes to close is varying with the number of nodes in the dialog.

At this point I think we are going to go with a browser Modal dialog (`window.openModal`) but I wanted to understand why this is happening. Ours is 32bit IE9. Also, this problem does not occur in IE8 or IE10+/Chrome. Is this just a javascript engine problem in IE9?

Comment: IE9 does have a slower JavaScript engine than more modern browers. But this is tough to diagnose, especially since you're talking about a library like jQueryUI (which potentially in and of itself has lots of inefficiencies and bloat). But it sounds like you may be overloading the DOM/browser with too many elements. I also wonder if there's overspecification in your selectors, such that when jQuery is attempting to find/unbind/remove all of the child elements, it's having to do some deep recursion.

Comment: I did try with plain javascript (no jquery in picture) but still had the same problem.

Comment: We'd need to see a [verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the issue, then. If you're having the problem with vanilla JS, try posting that code (but only as much code as is needed to reproduce the issue) to remove jQueryUI from the picture.

Comment: apart from the javascript problem, now i am also wondering why the question was downvoted....
It is difficult to reproduce the problem and it is most likely a javascript engine issue... i wanted to know if someone had faced this kind of problem before or if I am the pioneer here. Thanks for shedding some light.

Comment: Probably downvoted because the question is too vague for this forum. StackOverflow favors discrete questions about specific issues that can be easily verified.